# My wordpress posts appear in another language

Tags: php, wordpress

So, I've posted several articles in my wordpress site, and some people said that they see the articles in a different language. I checked those articles several times, and I was completely sure they were in English, but they sent me some screenshots, and really, they saw that post in another language. What should I do?
Here's an article for example: [click here](http://feel.news/university-of-sussex-student-story/)

Comment: I just get symbols.  What charset is your database set to use?

Comment: My DB character set is UTF8.

Comment: It is showing for me: `<span style="font-family: wingdings, 'zapf dingbats'; font-size: 14pt;">`  You need to use a different font.  If I change the font to something like `Verdana` I can read the content.

Comment: Could you tell me if you can read it now, please?

Comment: Yup I get it now, I will add this as an answer for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have set the content to use the font `<span style="font-family: wingdings, 'zapf dingbats'; font-size: 14pt;">`.

Try changing this to something else like `Verdana`.  Or if you wanted to include custom fonts, you could always play around with:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'MyWebFont';
  src:  url('myfont.woff2') format('woff2'),
        url('myfont.woff') format('woff');
}
```